# C# Ignoring Keydowns in ProcessKeyPreview

Tags: c#, events, keydown

What's going on you all.  I've overrided the ProcessKeypreview method, so that I can detect when the 'WASD' keys are being held, and then released.  However, I'm running into problems when there is a collision,  for instance when 'A' is pressed while 'W' is already being held down.  How can I prevent all other keydowns while a specific key is being held down?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m) 
{
    int msgVal = m.WParam.ToInt32();
    if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        switch((Keys)msgVal) {
        case Keys.W:
            Console.WriteLine("W being held");
            break;

        case Keys.A:
            Console.WriteLine("A being held");
            break;
        }
    }

    if (m.Msg == WM_KEYUP) {
        switch((Keys)msgVal) {
            case Keys.W:
                Console.WriteLine("W released");
                break;

            case Keys.A:
                Console.WriteLine("A released");
                break;
        }
    }  
return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);  
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't returning a bool value.  At least, it should return `return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);`.  Also, your constants are backwards.  `WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100`

Comment: your end goal is to know when certain keys are beeing pressed right?

Comment: Good catch, I'll edit it.  But in the meantime,  feel free to assume that the method works perfectly.

My end goal is to prevent the letter A's keydown from being triggered while the letter W's keydown is already being triggered.

Comment: That is not how games work.  Last key wins.  Try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a set (probably a `HashSet<Keys>`) of the `Keys` that are currently being pressed by `Add`ing the keys to the set on key-down and `Remove`ing the keys from the set on key-up.

Then, since you know how many keys are pressed, if you want to not process any more keys while a specific key is down, you can just check if your set `Contain`s the key. If it does, then `return true;`.

Your method should look like this:

```
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0101;
const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0100;
HashSet<Keys> keysDown = new HashSet<Keys>();
protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m) 
{
    int msgVal = m.WParam.ToInt32();
    if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        keysDown.Add((Keys)msgVal);
        switch((Keys)msgVal) {
        case Keys.W:
            Console.WriteLine("W being held");
            break;

        case Keys.A:
            Console.WriteLine("A being held");
            break;
        }
        if (keysDown.Contains(keyToCheck))
            return true;
    }

    if (m.Msg == WM_KEYUP) {
        switch((Keys)msgVal) {
            case Keys.W:
                Console.WriteLine("W released");
                break;

            case Keys.A:
                Console.WriteLine("A released");
                break;
        }
        keysDown.Remove((Keys)msgVal);
    } 

    return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
}
```

Since you didn't specify what key you're checking for (`"prevent all other keydowns while a specific key is being held down"`), I just left that as a variable, `keyToCheck`. You can change the conditions to change when to disregard keypresses.

Alternatively, if the key to check is a constant, then you don't need the `Set` and can instead just keep a `bool` for whether that key is down or not:

```
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0101;
const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0100;
bool keyToCheckDown = false;
protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m) 
{
    int msgVal = m.WParam.ToInt32();
    if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if ((Keys)msgVal == KEY_TO_CHECK)
            keyToCheckDown = true;
        switch((Keys)msgVal) {
        case Keys.W:
            Console.WriteLine("W being held");
            break;

        case Keys.A:
            Console.WriteLine("A being held");
            break;
        }
        // the second condition is necessary so that you don't "return true" the when the key to check is pressed.
        if (keyToCheckDown && (Keys)msgVal != KEY_TO_CHECK)
            return true;
    }

    if (m.Msg == WM_KEYUP) {
        switch((Keys)msgVal) {
            case Keys.W:
                Console.WriteLine("W released");
                break;

            case Keys.A:
                Console.WriteLine("A released");
                break;
        }
        if ((Keys)msgVal == KEY_TO_CHECK)
            keyToCheckDown = false;
    } 

    return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
}
```

Here the constant is `KEY_TO_CHECK`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Spectacular solution,  my friend!  I'm confident that this will work excellently.  Thank you for being thorough.